# Linq to text Select Last

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to find the last occurrence of specific field. I've tried different permientations but to no avail.

Here is what I have now. It works as far as it goes but not with a Select clause. The Select clause causes the query to crash.

```
Dim Qry = From lines In File.ReadAllLines(curMonth)
          Let Data = lines.Split(" ")
          Let LogDate = Data(0)
          Let Time = Data(1)
          Let DataType = Data(2)
          Let DutyStatus = Data(3)
          Let Memo = lines.Split("/")
          Let Location = Memo(0)
          Let LocationTag = Memo(1)
          Let CoDriver = Memo(2)
          Let DriverNumber = Memo(3)
          Let Status = Memo(5)
          Where DataType = "35"

For Each lines In Qry
    Debug.Print(lines.LogDate & ", " & lines.Time & ", " & lines.DutyStatus & ", " & lines.DataType _
      & ", " & lines.LocationTag & ", " & lines.CoDriver & ", " & lines.Status)
Next
```

Thanks

Here is some additional info.
Sample Data:

```
20130801 00:00 26 X /DRIVER/'Don Hall'/'1622'/290/'3.5.1.08'/
20130801 00:00 24 W /RULE//CAN2007/13.0/0.0/14.0/70.0/7.0/0/0/1/
20130801 00:00 31 C /POWER UNIT/'Tractor'/'8536'/1/''/'PY7341'/1374680419/''/''/''/''/''/''/''/''/0/''/'ON'/''/'Single'/
20130801 00:00 35 C /CODRIVER/'Margaret Hall'/'1623'/''/1/1365556442/
20130801 00:00 30 C /MOTOR CARRIER/'K-DAC Enterprises'/'3025 Sandhills RD., Baden, ON, N3A 3B8'/'3025 Sandhills RD., Baden, ON, N3A 3B8'/''/1/'1622'/'Don Hall'/1328079183/''/
20130802 00:00 03 X /MILES VEHICLE/94.0/1596267.0/1596361.0/2/
20130802 00:00 58 A /PREX/1//SCHED1/1//VCF/1//VMINOR/0//VMAJOR/0//POWERODOM/'1596267'//TOWEDODOM/'1596267'//TIME/'14:45'//LOCATION INSP/'Langley BC'/
20130802 00:00 04 X /MILES DRIVING/1596267.0/0.0/0.0/0.0/0.0/0.0/0.0/1596361.0/94.0/0/2/0.0/94.0/0.0/
20130802 00:00 25 X /PRINT/'20130803 01:23'/1/0/
20130802 12:45 32 X /TOWED UNIT/'Trailer'/'53566'/1/''/'K8601J'/1375453962/''/''/''/''/''/''/''/''/0/''/'ON'/''/'Single'/
```

This data builds until end of month when another file is started. (Each record starts with the date. This window is wrapping the lines.)

Sample needed from linq query:

```
20131021, 11:30, X, 35, CODRIVER, 'Margaret Hall', 0
```

I hope this helps you understand what I'm after.

Comment: Show how your input looks like and how should your output look like.

Comment: `Data` and `Memo` will share some data from each line that you are reading through. Also, this will load the entire file into memory before starting to parse the text (I am assuming it is text). There are much easier ways to accomplish text parsing than trying to read and parse it with LINQ.

Comment: Thanks. How do I add more Info to this thread? I just spent several minutes replying just to find out my comment was to long. In addition, when I pressed the Enter Key  and Ctrl Enter my comment was submitted instead of moving one line down. Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide sample output based on sample data provided and can you explain why that is considered the last occurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if moving the Where clause to just after the DataType assignment helps.  It looks to me that your query is reading every line and trying to split it the way you want, instead of just the lines you want parsed.  The Where clause should filter them out.:

```
Dim Qry = From lines In File.ReadAllLines(curMonth)
          Let Data = lines.Split(" ")
          Let LogDate = Data(0)
          Let Time = Data(1)
          Let DataType = Data(2)
          Where DataType = "35"
          Let DutyStatus = Data(3)
          Let Memo = lines.Split("/")
          Let Location = Memo(0)
          Let LocationTag = Memo(1)
          Let CoDriver = Memo(2)
          Let DriverNumber = Memo(3)
          Let Status = Memo(5)
          Select LogDate & "," & Time & "," & DutyStatus & "," & DataType _
                 & "," & LocationTag  & "," & CoDriver & "," & Status
```

Each entry in your query results will have a formatted string that you can use.  If you need a collection instead of outputting the data you can simply call the ToList method.

Comment: Thanks. I used ToList, got the count and returned the last item.

Comment: @Don6558 If this has fixed your issue, please remember to mark this answered.  Thanks.

Comment: I would love to. Where/How do I mark this question as answered? I see no "Answered" button. Never mind. I figured it out. Thanks.